# Splitting dataframes into multiple data frame with differing columns using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows. The first row indicates which group it is, and each group should be a separate data frame. But depending on the group, there may be other information, and the columns are not the same for all groups:

```
|A|10|15|20|Jeremy|Gonzales|
|A|6|30|22|Maria|Gonzales|
|B|5|14|14|Student|Physics|Jose|Enrique|
|B|10|14|4|Professor|Mathematics|John|Smith|
|C|Laboratory|Capacity|30|
|C|Library|Capacity|300|
```

I want group A, B, and C to be a different data frame. But they have differing columns:

First I am reading the pipe delimited file:

```
df = pandas.readcsv('path', sep = '|' index_col = False)
```

then I'm grouping the data frame based on the first column:

```
groups = [g for group, g in df.groupby('col 0')]
```

but this does not retain all the columns and shrinks some groups

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You should pre-process the data a bit before making dataframes:

```
with open('path') as f:
    data = [x.strip()[1:-1].split('|') for x in f.readlines()]

dfA = pd.DataFrame(x for x in data if x[0] == 'A')
dfB = pd.DataFrame(x for x in data if x[0] == 'B')
dfC = pd.DataFrame(x for x in data if x[0] == 'C')
```

Output:

```
   0   1   2   3       4         5
0  A  10  15  20  Jeremy  Gonzales
1  A   6  30  22   Maria  Gonzales

   0   1   2   3          4            5     6        7
0  B   5  14  14    Student      Physics  Jose  Enrique
1  B  10  14   4  Professor  Mathematics  John    Smith

   0           1         2    3
0  C  Laboratory  Capacity   30
1  C     Library  Capacity  300
```